# How do I constrain a <select> to its parent div's width?

Tags: html, css

My webpage has a `<select>` menu within a `<div>` parent. If the menu contains a very wide item, it overflows its parent's width (when closed). How do I truncate it instead?

I tried `flex-shrink: 1` but nothing happened. Am I using it correctly? Do I apply it to the `<select>` or the wide `<option>`? Or something else?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using flex display but `flex-shrink: 1` by itself didn't work, but it worked when I added `width: 100%`. Not sure why that made a difference but it did.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried applying a [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) to the select? Perhaps 100%? Here's [a pen](https://codepen.io/sharphosting/pen/PjEEqz) demonstrating it.

And another example of it provided by [John Weisz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788872/john-weisz):

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
}

select {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select>
        <option>My webpage has a select menu within a div parent. If the menu contains a very wide item, it overflows its parent's width (when closed). How do I truncate it instead?</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
<div>
```

Comment: Yes I already tried that. It doesn't work on my page like it does on yours. :-/